# Redux performance with large objects

Tags: javascript, json, performance, reactjs, redux

I am using Redux and React to build a web application. My application is an analytics application that renders a lot of data. I am running into performance issues when my store becomes large.

What is the preferred way of avoiding performance issues with large data in redux?

### Application Structure

My app is structured in a way where I have `settings` (small json), `results` (large json), and `calculate(settings)`. Calculate is deterministic and idempotent. My app renders settings metadata and the results in graphs, tables, etc.

Because calculate is deterministic and idempotent, I know results will not change when settings does not change. When settings do change my results may change. In other words, I'm comfortable relying on only settings to determine if I need to update my UI.

### Redux Behavior & Potential Solutions

My application is slow when I include results inside my store:

```
let settings = { foo: "bar" };
let results = calculate(settings);
Object.assign({}, state, { settings: settings, results: results });

//deterministic and idempotent
function calculate(settings) {
  return /*large json*/;
}
```

My application is fast when I reference but don't include results inside my store:

```
let settings = { foo: "bar" };
let results = calculate(settings);
Object.assign({}, state, { settings: settings, results: () => results });

//deterministic and idempotent
function calculate(settings) {
  return /*large json*/;
}
```

I know redux advises against storing functions, so an alternative is to save a  reference using a string...something like:

```
let settings = { foo: "bar" };
let calculationId = uuid(); //could also be a hash of settings if I want to avoid some false positive UI re-rendering
let results = calculate(settings);
setResults(calculationId, results);
Object.assign({}, state, { settings: settings, calculationId: calculationId });

//deterministic and idempotent
function calculate(settings) {
  return /*large json*/;
}

let fakeStore = { calculationId: null, results: null };

function setResults(calculationId, results) {
  fakeStore. calculationId = calculationId;
  fakeStore.results = results;
}

function getResults(calculationId) {
  if(fakeStore.calculationId === calculationId) {
    return fakeStore.results;
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid data access");
}

render() {
  let calculationId = this.props.calculationId;
  let results = getResults(calculationId);
}
```

Keeping large data outside of the store is tenable, but it seems like there may be better ways react supports this use case.

Using redux 3.7.1, react 15.4.2, react-redux 4.4.8

Answer (score 2):

Simply "saving values into the store" will not affect speed whatsoever.  It's how you *process* those values in your reducers, and *use* them in your UI that matter.  So, it's a bit hard to give specific advice, since you haven't given any info on how you're actually using that data.

In general, per the other comment, use of memoized selectors (created by the Reselect library) is helpful for only recalculating expensive derived values when the inputs actually change.

For more information on improving Redux usage performance, please see:

- The [Redux FAQ entry on scaling and performance](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-scaling)
- The [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links)
- My blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/)

Comment: Thank you. These resources are very helpful! I'll look into how my data is being processed. I suspect somewhere I am accidentally triggering shallow equality checks that traverse across a few larger objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). Do the result object reference change after each calculation? If that's the case, this small library should help you.

Comment: Yea, the result changes after most calculations.

Comment: If your results are calculated and depends on other state properties, I would recommend using selectors instead of storing the results in the store.

Reselect library, which I linked, gives you performance boost, as it will recalculate only if input has changed (in your case - the settings).

Comment: The calculation isn't the performance bottleneck. I re-calculate rarely and when necessary.

Comment: The calculation itself may not be a bottleneck, but the change of results object reference may be. If so, do not keep result in the store itself. See [link](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)