# Redux seems slow when saving large collection to store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Simplified situation:**

I am working on a live application that needs to save around 650 objects as an array into a `Redux store`.

The application holds a ReactJs - Redux - ImmutableJs - Reselect techstack. But I have identified the slowdown to actually saving the data into the Redux store.

Using ImmutableJs is irrelevant. I have created POC's with and without this framework and the performance did not change.

Following code is my `SearchReducer`

```
const searchReducer = (state = fromJS(defaultState), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SEARCHMUSICIAN:      
      const { searchTerm, results } = action.payload;

      return state.set('searchTerm', searchTerm)
                  .set('foundMusicians', fromJS(results));

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

What can explain the slowdown? Is Redux actually slow with bigger collections or large amounts of data at once? 
Is there a flag or configuration that I am missing that would increase the Redux performance?

[image: Performance example without Immutable]
[image: Performance example with Immutable]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redux performance with large objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358420/redux-performance-with-large-objects)

Comment: @MikhailLitvinov Not a duplicate though. I did already see the other post. However, the recommendations are about reading from the store and using memoization. 
In my case, the reading, retrieving and displaying data is not the issue. The actual saving to the store is the issue...

Comment: Have you timed the duration of those 2 set statements (`console.time` on each side)? How big is the data inside these 650 objects? The store itself isn't doing special things to slow stuff down the code inside redux is very simple. How are you measuring perf? Perf of your UI can be dependent on other things like redux-connect, use of PureComponent etc etc

Comment: your example code does not have any console.log statements so I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that redux is the bottleneck and not re rendering 650 items because you provide a new state that has 650 items to (re)render. Using [connect](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) with a memoized function returning the item may skip some renders but without code it's just a guess. Also fromJS probably returns a new reference every time anyway. Assuming you do client side filtering. If you search on the server then you get a new reference every time.

Comment: @Dominic my UI performance is irrelevant. Everything is doing fine except the save to redux.

Comment: @HMR I have remove the console logs to avoid bloating the code example. The rerendering has no effect on performance. Like I stated before: the console logs were directly around the redux statement. Both with immutable and without.

Comment: What we are trying to say is that redux itself is not slow, it's a tiny simple library which runs a function and if that functions returns a new object, it fires an update even on listeners. You need to identify your bottleneck and be more specific, setting 650 objects on to an object in vanilla javascript (which is redux) is not slow. I have set 10,000 nested objects to a redux store before and had no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we got it fixed now.
Apparently Redux is very slow with big arrays. 
I have converted the dispatched payload to an object and now the saving-to-store delay goes from 2-3 seconds to 30-50 milliseconds.

My guess is that Redux has trouble with internal optimizations when using larger arrays. 
The saving-to-store delay also increases exponentially when the array size increases. This also does not happen when using an object and increasing the amount of properties or keys.

Comment: Can you expand on the data structure you moved to that was faster? I also have an array of points (30,000) and tried changing it to an object where each point was a property and saw no difference in speed/slowness.

Comment: Ah never mind, I isolated the issue to my Map render component.

Comment: How did you isolate the issue to Map Render please and how did you solve the issue? We are facing the same issue with our Map Markers in [`react-google-maps`](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps)

Comment: React google maps is slow with a large set of markers. When I changed to native api integration the speed increased by many factors. Look here: https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/495